# Adding new column in target in GCP Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

How to add a new column in target with static values in GCP Data Fusion (with/without wrangler)?

Comment: What is your use case? It would also help to see what did you try, what your pipeline looked like, etc. for us to replicate your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is add a new column named `static` with the same constant value for each record, say `x`, you can do so using the [set-column directive](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382107931/Set+Column+directive) in wrangler. The expression would look as follows:

```
set-column :static 'x'
```

This directive should be entered in the terminal you see at the bottom when wrangler is open.

Comment: cool :-) thanks a lot. It is working fine.